# How do i get site url dynamically in admin twig file in opencart?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I am trying to get my site url like; https://www.example.com/ in admin twig file for my custom module.
Can anyone help me please?

I tried this, but no result;

{{ HTTPS_CATALOG }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your corresponding controller file define:

```
$data['site_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

in corresponding twig file you  can call this data:

```
{{ site_url }}
```

If the answer are useful for you, can you mark it "This answer is useful"